# How to make shell execute a command prior to every user input command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a command to be executed before shell starts to execute the user passed command,i tried using trap with DEBUG signal, but that did not happen.

I have registered trap in /etc/profile.

> trap 'echo "my_command"' DEBUG

Whats happening now is:

> sw0:root:root> pwd
>
> /root
>
> my_command
>
> sw0:root:root>

What i want is:

> sw0:root:root> pwd
>
> my_command
>
> /root
>
> sw0:root:root>

Bash Version Used:

> GNU bash, version 2.04.0(1)-release (powerpc-unknown-linux-gnu)

I want my command to be executed prior to every command entered by user in shell,how do i do that?

Please help me on this,i tried lot of googling but that does not help.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  What is it you're really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for something like [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html):

> The contents of this variable are executed as a regular Bash command just before Bash displays a prompt.

Comment: No i need <my_command>to be executed before shell starts executing the command passed by user. PROMPT_COMMAND is executed by shell after executing the command passed by user.
In above case before shell executes "pwd" it should execute "my_command"

Comment: `PROMPT_COMMAND` is executed when Bash displays a prompt which is *before* a user types a command.

Answer (score 0):

My example

```
function preexec() {
  echo "Preexec command"
}

trap 'preexec' DEBUG
```

Result is

```
# pwd
Preexec command
/home/robert
```

Comment: I'm using this version of shell "GNU bash, version 2.04.0(1)-release",according to the man page of this version PROMPT_COMMAND is executed after User's input is executed.

Comment: Sorry, then. I think there is no way how to do it :(